# x position after TCPDF Write call

Tags: tcpdf

I am using TCPDF->Write with $firstline=TRUE so that I can emit a line from a longer paragraph and then have control over where the next line goes (e.g. to flow onto next page or another box on the same page). This works fine, and avoids having to explicitly measure string lengths and where to wrap - TCPDF does that for me.

However, sometimes I want to change the text characteristics mid-line (colour, weigt, insert an image, whatever). So I give the text to Write, and assuming it all fits (Write doesn't return any remaining string), I can set up the new characteristic and then give the next bit to Write.

The problem is the x position seems to reset to the left margin after the Write call, whether or not it has any text left over. GetX doesn't give me the position I need. It appears this value *is* in the code in TCPDF->$endlinex but I have to un-protect that variable in order to use it, which isn't a good solution.

Is there a correct way to get the x position at the end of the string written after a Write call?

(I tried $firstblock, but that doesn't seem to make any difference whether it is TRUE or FALSE)

(I know I could mark it up as HTML, but my source isn't HTML to start with and the WriteHTML call doesn't offer the control over text flow that I need.)

Answer (score 1):

What version of TCPDF are you using?

I ran the following code with the latest version as at the time of writing (6.2.9) and the X position did not get reset after the calls to `Write()`.

```
$pdf = new TCPDF();
$pdf->SetPrintHeader( false );
$pdf->SetPrintFooter( false );
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetMargins( 10, 10, 10, 10 );
echo $pdf->GetX(), "\n";
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica' );
$pdf->Write( 5, 'This is a test.' );
echo $pdf->GetX(), "\n";
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica', 'B' );
$pdf->Write( 5, 'This is a test.' );
echo $pdf->GetX(), "\n";
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica' );
$pdf->Write( 5, 'This is a test.' );
echo $pdf->GetX(), "\n";
$pdf->output( 'test.pdf', 'F' );
```

When I ran this script, the output was as follows:

```
10.00125
34.939816666667
61.762216666667
86.700783333333
```

...and the resulting PDF had the string "This is a test." all on one line, in regular, bold, regular, as you would expect from reading the code.

I would be curious to know what the result of this script is when you run it.

Comment: It's 6.2.8. I get exactly the same as you when running your code, but the point is I am using the $firstline=TRUE parameter to Write with $txt. However, if I set all the parameters up to that one to NULL, it still works as above. But I have now discovered if I set $ln=TRUE (which I don't really see should have any effect on the x position afterwards) X is 10 after that first Write in your example.

Comment: ... and actually, that seems to be the case whether or not $firstline=TRUE. Hence... $pdf->Write( 5, 'This is a test.', '', FALSE, 'L', TRUE, NULL, FALSE, FALSE);

Comment: After deeper investigation I have discovered that there is an error in the documentation. Whilst the documentation for Write() says that there are two values, it turns out the Write() function simply passes $ln into the Cell() function, which accepts *three* values for $ln. If you have a look at the documentation for the Cell() function you'll see that when a value of 1 is passed in it moves the cursor "to the beginning of the next line". It goes on to say that "Putting 1 is equivalent to putting 0 and calling Ln() just after." I tried a value of 2 and unfortunately it still reset X to 10.

Comment: FWIW, I have updated the documentation for Write() for the $ln parameter and issued a pull request on the main Github repo.

Comment: Many thanks. Having looked at $ln for Cell, I think I was misinterpreting entirely what the intention of $ln in Write was in the first place - I read it as meaning whether the initial y was relative the top or bottom of the line (i.e. text above or below y), not what happened to it afterwards. I'll change this next time I'm looking at the code that uses Write.